# JpaItemWriter MultiThreader Primary Key Violation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using jpaItemWriter with Multi Threading.
But i keep getting SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000 Primary Key Violation.Although i am fetching distinct records and inserting the same.
Is JpaItemWriter ThreadSafe.? In multi threading how to make Processor and writer thread safe,in order to avoid exceptions like above.
Some times i also get the below Exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
o.h.e.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch  : HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: (conn=629417) Duplicate entry
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `inserting the same`: if you are inserting the same records, I'm not surprised you have a `Duplicate entry` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `JpaItemWriter` is thread-safe (As mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html)).

Using a multi-threaded step with database readers and writers is not the best option, I recommend using a partitioned step instead.

Comment: Thanks. But how does partitioned step work in the case of JpaPagingItemReader or JdbcPagingItemReader

Comment: .Can you please elaborate on how to implement the partitioned step with regards to Pagination Reader

Comment: You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java

Comment: Thanks sir.I have gone through the example.But in my case my primary key is alpha numerical,so i cant use max ,min function to calculate the target size.Is it okay if use a query to reteive total count and calculate the target size.....?

Comment: My Question is even though the JpaItemWriter and JpaPagingItemReader are thread safe ,why do we encounter such Issues like primary key violation or transaction getting locked..?

Comment: Yes, you have full control on how to partition data.